# Hive: how to find the total number of column in table in hql query?

Tags: hive

I need make an Sql query into Hql query.

```
select count(column_name) from user_tab_columns where table_name='EMP_TABLE';
```

i do not know how  to make it into an hql query if any one know please assist me.

Comment: Error - Table not found 'user_tab_columns'

Comment: Yes I execute the use dbname and my query.

Comment: No its not working,am stuck up on that issue only.

Answer (score 2):

I'm pretty sure Hive doesn't have this kind of metadata information available in a nice tabular format. You could look into querying the metastore directly, but that's ugly, and not really what you want anyway.

If you just want to know the number of columns in a Hive table, you can do that through a shell script that calls hive, for example:

```
hive -S -e 'describe my_table' | wc -l
```